# Django: how to allow null value

Tags: django

I have the following Django model:

```
from django.db import models
class AlertCalendar(models.Model):
    alert_calendar_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, blank=True, editable=False)
    start_time = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    end_time = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    start_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I want to create an instance of this model where all of the fields except the id are set to `null`, but when I try to do so I get the following error:

```
{
    "start_time": [
        "This field may not be null."
    ],
    "end_time": [
        "This field may not be null."
    ],
    "start_date": [
        "This field may not be null."
    ],
    "end_date": [
        "This field may not be null."
    ]
}
```

it is also the case when only one of these values is set to `null`, yet I defined the fields using both `null=True` and `blank=True`, so why can't I create this instance?

Comment: Where exactly are these errors coming from?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm not sure, they're not explicitly in my code

Comment: But you're doing something to get them. What, exactly? Is it from the admin, from an API request you're sending, what?

Comment: @JessicaChambersHow did you try creating the instance?

Comment: I send an API request

Comment: @JessicaChambers I have put an answer on how can we create an instance with null values.So once you call the api, you can perform that operation.Do you have a different requirement?

Comment: Then show the code that is responding to that API request. Presumably there is some kind of serializer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign `None` to each field for creating an instance with a null value.

```py
AlertCalendar.objects.create(start_time = None, end_time = None, start_date = None, end_date = None)
```

This would create an instance with the specified fields as `null`

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, please also upvote! :)

Answer (score 1):

As @Daniel Roseman presumed, the error response is from the serializer. Serializer class should be something like

```
class AlertCalendarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    start_time = serializers.TimeField(required=False, allow_null=True)
    end_time = serializers.TimeField(required=False, allow_null=True)
    start_date = serializers.DateField(required=False, allow_null=True)
    end_date = serializers.DateField(required=False, allow_null=True)
```

This will solve.